# Grunt task to set JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, javascript, gruntjs, jsdoc, java-home

I am using [grunt-jsdoc](https://github.com/krampstudio/grunt-jsdoc-plugin) to manage the execution of [jsdoc](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc) command, which depends on Java and needs to have the JAVA_HOME environment variable set. Assuming they already have node.js and Java, I'm trying to limit the local developer setup (on either Linux or Windows) to:

1. Checkout the project
2. run `npm install`

I have this working on Linux by using the [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) plugin and running a task like this right before the jsdoc task:

```js
// left out the part where I don't execute this task if JAVA_HOME already set
shell: {
  getjavahome_linux: {
    command: 'readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::"',
    options: {
      callback: function(err, stdout, stderr, cb) { 
        process.env.JAVA_HOME = stdout; 
        cb(); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I have not been able to find a similar command for Windows, to say nothing of other platforms. My question:

A) Is there a better approach in Grunt that does not require these platform-specific commands?

OR

B) If not, anyone have a Windows command that will do the equivalent of the Linux version above?

Note: actually setting JAVA_HOME inside the shell command does not work with grunt-jsdoc, but getting the output and setting `process.env.JAVA_HOME` works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JAVA_HOME env var check becomes a simple warning since version 0.3.3 of grunt-jsdoc

And since version 0.5.0, it doesn't require the Java version of jdsoc anymore. It fully runs on node.js

Answer (score 0):

On windows, I use cygwin shell (the git-bash version) to run Grunt where JAVA_HOME is set...

But it should work from the windows cmd, I've juste tried:

test.js

```
console.log(process.env.JAVA_HOME);
```

cmd.exe

```
set JAVA_HOME=D:\path
node test.js
```

displays the path

Comment: But that's what I'm trying to avoid: the developer having to set the environment variable themselves. Yes I know it's only one more step but on a large team if I can make this automatic we'll save time/trouble.

Comment: Please open an issue on Github, and I'll implement some kind of force option where the env verification could be bypassed