# JSDoc without Java?

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, jsdoc

I'm trying to incorporate J[SDoc into my Grunt](https://github.com/krampstudio/grunt-jsdoc-plugin) deployment process. When I run it, I get the following error (expectedly):

```
>> JAVA_HOME is not set. Jsdoc requires Java to run.
Fatal error: Bad argument
```

I know that JSDoc is java-based, but I'm hoping to remove Java from the equation wholly. Is there a way to do this with the existing grunt plugin, or another that runs the process in Node only?

I don't want to add Java just for one task. Is this a fool's errand?

Comment: A down vote with no reasoning? Please, if you're going to down vote me please provide feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to do this from the current grunt jsdoc plugin. The issue is with the underlying jsdoc utility of course. You can track their progress toward supporting node.js instead of Rhino here:

https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/93

However, a couple notes about that error you're seeing.

- At least on Linux, as long as `java` is in the path, you can safely ignore that error and it will still generate.
- see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722953/grunt-task-to-set-java-home) for some other discussion about JAVA_HOME and grunt-jsdoc-plugin

Comment: The last versions of jsdoc and grunt-jsdoc are pure JavaScript, Java isn't required anymore.

Answer (score 4):

The [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org) dependency on Java, required by Mozilla Rhino, has been removed in JSDoc 3.3.0. The [JSDoc GitHub page](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc) states:

> Native support for Node.js is available in JSDoc 3.3.0 and later. JSDoc supports Node.js 0.10 and later.

JSDoc v3.3.0 is still in alpha release status (3.3.0-alpha4 was released on Jan 26, 2014), so to install the latest alpha version use:

```
npm install jsdoc@"<=3.3.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem, and built a little Grunt plugin wrapping JSDoc 3.3 (no need for Java, all running in Node):

https://github.com/usrz/javascript-grunt-jsdoc-ng